# Haskell - Ambiguous type variable

Tags: haskell

I couldn't find an answer to my question among several ambiguous type variable error questions.

Basically I want to take type information to the value level. The last line in this example fails.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Test where

data Typ = TInteger | TString deriving Show

data Empty = Empty
data a ## b = Cons a b

class Typical a b | a -> b where
    typical :: a -> b

instance Typical Empty [Typ] where
    typical _ = []

instance Typical Integer Typ where
    typical _ = TInteger

instance Typical String Typ where
    typical _ = TString

instance (Typical a Typ, Typical b [Typ]) => Typical (a ## b) [Typ] where
    typical _ = typical (undefined :: a) : typical (undefined :: b)
```

Here is the first error message:

```
Test.hs:27:17:
Could not deduce (Typical a0 Typ) arising from a use of `typical'
from the context (Typical a Typ, Typical b [Typ])
  bound by the instance declaration at Test.hs:26:10-67
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Typical String Typ -- Defined at Test.hs:23:10
  instance Typical Integer Typ -- Defined at Test.hs:20:10
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Typical a0 Typ)
In the first argument of `(:)', namely `typical (undefined :: a)'
In the expression:
  typical (undefined :: a) : typical (undefined :: b)
In an equation for `typical':
    typical _ = typical (undefined :: a) : typical (undefined :: b)
```

I just don't get it.

What is `a0` here? Could it be that the `a` from my last line is not identified with that from the 2nd last line?

Where should I put a type signature and why?

Please enlighten me!

Comment: Adding a functional dependency states that one type is [uniquely determined by another](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies). I believe you need to either remove one of the instances of `Typical a Typ` or create specific instances for each possible variation of your combined instance.

Comment: @Mokosha: The functional dependency is `a -> b`, not `b -> a`, so I don't think instances must be removed. I don't think I got the second part of your last sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I have a solution, but I don't know if this is the cleanest workaround.

Adding `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` makes the code compile. This makes it possible to identify `a0` with `a` from the error message (corresponding to the `a`s from the last two lines of the code).

Please comment!

Comment: `ScopedTypeVariables` is the right way to get what you want. Otherwise, variables in the local type annotations are all implicitly quantified. Independently, if you never need the actual value of the first argument of `typical`, it's probably better to use a proxy: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html#t:Proxy

Comment: @kosmikus: Thanks. After following that reference I have the impression that `Data.Reflection` does what I tried to construct here.